# TLS session reuse over new TCP connection

Tags: security, tcp, ssl

This is after my [question about http and tls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705715/http-persistent-connection-and-ssl-session).
It seems that there is no mandate per RFC to invalidate an established TLS session if the underlying TCP connection is closed (and then reopened).
Is it safe to reuse the established TLS session over the new TCP connection?
Are there any known attacks (even at theoritical level) that could exploit this?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Indeed there is such a mandate in [RFC 2246 -- TLS 1.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246) if the TCP connection is closed without sending a `close_notify` alert: see section 7.2.1 of the RFC 2246. This mandate was widely ignored in implementations that otherwise followed RFC 2246. Acknowledging this, [TLS 1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346#section-7.2.1) and [TLS 1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2.1) have eliminated the requirement.

TLS/SSL security does not rely on any properties of TCP, so things that happen at that level should not matter. In particular it should not matter whether you try to resume a TLS session on the same TCP connection or on a new TCP connection.

Comment: Thank you!Is it safe to assume that any implementation I use will exhibit this behavior?

Comment: @user384706: There are many implementations out there so I can't say for certain.