# Is there a way to change the SSL handshake timeout in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, iis

One of our clients has a server in the US that needs to access our APIs, that are hosted in Brazil. Our API is very fast and can process large requests in less than 100ms, but unfortunately the latency between the servers is really big (400ms in most cases).

The issue is that when the first request between the server occurs in a while, the protocol needs to do several roundtrips to handshake the SSL, making this request more than 2 or 3 seconds long. The subsequent requests are acceptable (500ms).

I know that we can just use QUIC/HTTP3, but unfortunately, the client application uses a legacy technology that does not support it, and we are stuck in HTTP 2.

[image: QUIC]

Our client asked me if we can change the "handshake" timeout, so that there are fewer slow requests and less handshakes. I searched the web and did not find anything about it.

So, I want to know of it is possible.

I am using ASP.NET 7 and webapi in an "webapp" managed server, running windows.

Comment: Check the `ServicePointManager` and try to set the `DefaultConnectionLimit`.Refer this [doc](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/4113944/Could-not-create-SSL-TLS-secure-channel) once.

Comment: The handshake resets if the TCP connection resets (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705786/2791540)), so even if you extend the handshake timeout, you might still see sessions getting dropped and restarted.